# Check the maximum number of classes in package

Tags: java, package, static-analysis

In the suite of static analysis I'd like to have a check that limits the number of classes or files in a single package. Is there something like this readymade available, preferrable in Findbugs, Checkstyle or Sonar Qube since we already use those.

I know I can build such a check, e.g. with JDepend, but if available I'd prefer something that I just need to configure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Findbugs does not have this kind of check.
Checkstyle also.
Sonar either.

Check

> http://metrics.sourceforge.net/ :
>   It seems you could configure it to check number of classes on package level.

or

> http://www.jarchitect.com/Metrics